# How to update an MS Access database using a dataset in visual basic?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I am currently working on a project on visual Basic 2010, what i am stuck on now is updating my MS Access database triggered by a button click.

I already have the connection and data adapter established and i generated a data set for the data adapter, and i have used the data set. what i am trying to do is read from a data grid view entries the user have typed in and save these changes to the data set, and finally save the dataset back into the database using the oledbdataadapter.update(dataset) command. I tried everything and i have been stuck for a while, there are no errors in the code and I can see the changes made to the dataset are successful and i can view them (i am getting the "update successful" at the end of the try so i am sure the code is executing till then and not going to exception), but i simply don't see the changes in the database.
below is the code, i will appreciate any help you can offer thank you.

```
          For j As Integer = 6 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
        Try

            Dim s As String = DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value
            Dim Quantaties As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataSet21.Tables("Stock").Rows.Count


                Dim foundRow As DataRow = DataSet21.Tables("Stock").Rows.Find(i)

                If foundRow IsNot Nothing Then
                    If foundRow(1) = s Then
                        DataSet21.Tables("Stock").Rows(i).Item(7) = Quantaties

                        DataSet21.AcceptChanges()
                        Try
                            Dim builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDbDataAdapter1)
                            Me.Validate()
                            OleDbDataAdapter1.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
                            OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet21.Stock)
                            DataSet21.AcceptChanges()
                            MsgBox("Update successful")

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox("Update failed")
                        End Try
                    End If

                End If
            Next
            BindingSource1.EndEdit()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply.
I guess both ways work OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet21.Stock) and OleDbDataAdapter1.Update("DataSet21"), because i figured out what was wrong with my code. the problem was in the DataSet21.AcceptChanges() i should not have placed it before the OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet21.Stock).

the OleDbDataAdapter.update() saves changes done in the dataset to the database and the dataset.acceptchanges() makes the dataset save the changes done to it making it seem that it doesn't have changes in it anymore. so the OleDbDataAdapter.update() was not executing since the dataset didn't have changes done to it because of the dataset.acceptchanges()

so what i did was remove dataset.acceptchanges() and it finally worked. my code looks like this now.

```
      For j As Integer = 6 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count
        Try

            Dim s As String = DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value
            Dim Quantaties As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataSet21.Tables("Stock").Rows.Count


                Dim foundRow As DataRow = DataSet21.Tables("Stock").Rows.Find(i)

                If foundRow IsNot Nothing Then
                    If foundRow(1) = s Then
                        DataSet21.Tables("Stock").Rows(foundRow(0) - 2).Item(7) = Quantaties

                        Try
                            BindingSource1.EndEdit()
                            OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet21.Stock)


                            MsgBox("Update successful")


                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox("Update failed")
                        End Try
                    End If

                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
```

Comment: Since the `update` method will work on either the `DataSet` or a specific table in the `DataSet`, I have deleted my answer.  I'm glad it is working for you now.